# Spring Integration S3 'beanName' must not be empty

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to use S3 inbound channel adapter to download files from S3. Here is my config:

```
s3.xml:
<int:chain input-channel="s3ReaderChannel" output-channel="uncompressPayloadChannel">
 <int:service-activator ref="s3Bean" method="generateS3ObjectHash" />
 <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter 
               bucket="${s3.bucket}"
               session-factory="s3SessionFactory"
               auto-create-local-directory="true"
               auto-startup="false"
               filename-pattern="*.gz"
               local-directory="."
               local-filename-generator-expression="#this"
               temporary-file-suffix=".transffering"
               remote-directory="/remote/mytransfers"
               local-filter="acceptAllFilter"/>
</int:chain>

<bean id="s3SessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.integration.aws.support.S3SessionFactory"/>




aws-credentials.xml:
<!-- Define global credentials for all the AWS clients -->
<aws-context:context-credentials>
<aws-context:instance-profile-credentials/>
<aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${aws.accesskey}"
                                secret-key="${aws.secretkey}"/>
</aws-context:context-credentials>

<!-- Define global region -->
<aws-context:context-region region="${aws.region}"/>
```

When I try to execute, I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main"` 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected 
exception parsing XML document from file`; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanName' must not be empty
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
...30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanName' must not be empty
at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:58)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:46)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.addPropertyReference(BeanDefinitionBuilder.java:226)
at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.AbstractPollingInboundChannelAdapterParser.doParse(AbstractPollingInboundChannelAdapterParser.java:64)
   ...20 more
`
```

From the stack trace, AbstractPollingInboundChannelAdapterParser.java:64 is about outputChannel, which I dont understand since it is in a chain.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, Inbound Channel Adapter is the beginning of the flow and it can't be declared in the `<chain>` at all. More over you have that mess like you declare it after some `<int:service-activator>`.

You have to move the `<int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>` outside of the `<chain>` and keep in mind that this one is going to be the start of your flow.

I'm not sure what made you think wrong way, but looks like you need more info from the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/).

Comment: Usecase: I have another service dumping files to an S3 bucket. Based on a logic, I derive the file that I need and I pull it from this S3 bucket. So, I did put it in a chain where my service-activator derives the logic.

Comment: Well, for that purpose you need to use `<int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway>` instead. The Inbound Channel Adapter is always a start point of the flow. It can't react to any event. It is just polling by the task scheduler. It just ins't going to work as you expected. You should reconsider your point of view to this component.

Comment: I tried that but, for DOWNLOAD operation, it forces the payload to be 'java.io.File' type. Why?

Comment: What do you mean "Why?". That's how `this.transferManager.download(bucket, key, targetFile)` API works. What's wrong with that? You have a name for the file, you create it locally and send as a `payload` to gateway for downloading remote content to this local file.

Comment: I thought I would have options to save it to local directory and use my payload to have other information like the list of filenames. Never mind, I will try this approach. Thanks for your help.